# Return whether the given character is in a list or not without the use of the elem function and recursion

Tags: list, haskell, higher-order-functions

I have to make the `elementIsInList :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` function that should behave the same way the `elem` function would behave, but I can't use recursion and of course, the `elem` function itself. I thought about implementing it using the `filter` function, but I can't figure out how `filter` works. Am I on the right track?

`elementIsInList x xs = filter(x==xs) xs`

Comment: What you need is `null` to check if the list is empty or not.

Comment: you could also use `any` with signature `Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x == xs` makes not much sense, `x` is an element to look for, whereas `xs` is the entire list of elements. You can make use of a lambda expression:

```
filter (\x -> x == y) xs
```

or of an infix operator section:

```
filter (x ==) xs
```

Furthermore you need to check if the list is empty. [**`null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) will return `True` if the list is empty, and `False` if it is not. You will then need to negate the result with [**`not :: Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:not).